# Problemas con carpeta en visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, vscode, cloud, drive

Ayuda por favor, yo estaba trabajando en visual studio code, con una carpeta que guardaba en one drive, pero mi almacenamiento en la nube se llenó y seleccione la carpeta y le di a "liberar espacio" después le di a "mantener siempre en este dispositivo" y luego movi la carpeta fuera de one drive al escritorio.

Pero ahora cuando entro a visual studio code, solo aparecen dos archivos de todos los que tenía guardado ahí y ni siquiera están los últimos cambios que hice en esos archivos, intenté con "restaurar a versiones anteriores" pero no hay versiones anteriores, volvi a pasar la carpeta a one drive y no se recuperó nada, no sé qué hacer, yo tenía la opción de autoguardo en visual studio code y cada vez que volvía a entrar al probrama, el área de trabajo estaba como la había dejado, por eso no entiendo porque tengo este problema ahora.

Comment: ¿Has oido hablar de Git y los repositorios remotos? Tienes Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, entre otros. Usar OneDrive para esto es un poco *ugh*. Deja OneDrive para documentos e imágenes, incluso para divertidos videos de gatitos, pero para programación usa repositorios de programación. Suerte con tu búsqueda de solución al problema, sólo tú sabes lo que has podido hacer moviendo cosas de un lado a otro.

Comment: Creo que te volaste la carpeta oculta de `git`, revisa si la tienes en algún lado. Si está presente, puedes moverla y en teoría, tendrías el historial de cambios.